# Laravel PHPUnit mock Session between multiple Http Tests

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm writing an e-commerce where a non-authenticated user can add items to it's cart (using the session_id as a reference).

When the user logs in, all the items stored with its' session_id are transferred to its' customer_id.

e.g.

Table cart before login

```
customer_id | session_id | product_id | quantity
null          sess_123a    1            22
```

Table cart after login

```
customer_id | session_id | product_id | quantity
8             null         1            22
```

I'm trying to write a test for this feature but my test requires two HTTP calls, the "add to cart" (while not being logged in) and the "login" call.

While in the browser it works fine since the session_id is the same between multiple requests, in my test it keeps generating new session ids for each request.

```
$this->get("/change_cart_quantity/1/22"); // Session id sess_123abc
$response = $this->post("/auth/login", [
    'email' => 'test@mail.com',
    'password' => 'test',
]); // Session id sess_456cde
```

Is there a way to tell PHPUnit to use the same session_id between these two requests?
I know there is a "withSession" method but it cannot overwrite the "sessionId".

I may end up not using the sessionId but use a custom id stored inside the session, but honestly I don't like this approach.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: @KenLee those questions have similar titles, but the linked one does not use Laravel. Is that answer compatible with Laravel's implementation of session?

Comment: You shouldn't really try to preserve the session itself but you can use a combination of [`@depends`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html?#depends) and [passing specific session data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#sessions-and-authentication) to get what you need. The `@depends` also ensures the order that your tests run in because normally there's no guarantees

Comment: Presumably, you have another test to check things can be added to the basket, is it within your scope to possibility to mock the session data in the second test or do you need to test the transaction?

You could use `@depends previous_test_function_name_here` on the second test, remembering to return the session data from the first test and passing it to the next one, `test_function_two($sessionData)`

Comment: It appears I didn't read comment above, oops

Comment: You don't have to call 2 endpoints in your test... you have to set your desired initial conditions (initial session data) and then do the call to the other endpoint where you are going to trigger the change... It is really important that you read the [**documentation**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication) a frameworks offers because you are not a magician nor a developer with 1000 years of experience...

Comment: @matiaslauriti agreed! use session helpers to build up the data as it should. Laravel has weird side effects when calling http calls multiple times in a test.

Comment: Yes, I ended up not using Sesssion::getId(), instead I created a custom attribute in my session and I faked it.